# 503 error for couchdb with ingress on AKS

Tags: nginx, couchdb, azure-aks

Thanks, i am setting up a couch db instance on AKS cluster, using the operator (not the chart), and i can access the cluster without issues with portforward, while when trying to expose it using nginx ingress, i get 503 error Service Temporarily Unavailable.
the ingress controller is external

Thank you

couch db instance:

```
apiVersion: couchdb.databases.cloud.ibm.com/v1
kind: CouchDBCluster
metadata:
  name: couch
  namespace: db
spec:
  size: 1
  disk: 1Gi
  memory: 1Gi
  cpu: 500m
  storageClass: "managed"
  environment:
    adminPassword: "admin"
```

the ingress (i am testing the ingress without tls):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: db
spec:
  ingressClassName: public-nginx
  rules:
  - host: couch.db.svc
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: couch
            port:
              number: 5984
```